# Replace core login function

Tags: plugin-development

I want to replace the login function with a custom one validating against Office 365 oAuth.  I already have the connection to MS coded, but I can't find a way to replace the core login function.  I can see the "before login" hook, but that would still display the login screen.  Is there any way to accomplish via plugin, or do I have to alter the core code to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Have you made some progress on this topic? I am also interest in using Office 365 logins for Craft.

Comment: I did, but I had to modify a core file to make it work the way I wanted.  It was a small modification, but still probably not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish can be done with a plugin.

Perhaps this OAuth plugin could at least offer some boilerplate for you: https://dukt.net/craft/oauth/

dukt's github also has some provider-specific plugins: https://github.com/dukt